# name WebRequestMethods does not exist in current context and FTPWebResopnce could not be found

Tags: c#

I am doing coding for file download but it is WebRequestMethods does not exist showing..

```
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://something.com/temp.exe");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "1234");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        FileStream file = File.Create(@"c:\temp\temp.exe");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
        int read;
        //reader.Read(

        while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            file.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        file.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Above is my code please direct me.!

Comment: Have you added `using System.Mail` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider referencing `System` Assembly and add `System.Mail` namespace in your code.

**EDIT**:-
The .NET Compact framework doesn't support System.Net.Mail or System.Web.Mail. You should probably look for extensions.

Comment: I tried it but when i added system.mail it is showing Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) It is compact framework... is it posible in Compact framework (Windows CE)??

Comment: @user4265170 - .NET Compact framework doesn't support System.Net.Mail

Comment: then how can i solve this prblome...?? i just want download file from my ftp server in Compact framework i.e. on windows embedded Compact Edition 6.0..>! please help\

Comment: @Siddh - You can call a service which can send E-mails for you or you cansearch for some extensions like this:- http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/7e16eccb-dc9e-4559-c79c-cfaad631ac15.htm